# Redirecting with mask from one host to the other

Tags: redirect, rewrite

I have a domain abc123.com and a second domain def456.com.
I've setup def456.com/forum.  However I want users to goto and only see forum.abc123.com.

The forum is SMF.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?
Maybe I have to use Apache ReWrite rules?  I'm not sure.

To be clear, I never want the user to know they are actually browsing on the def456.com domain.

thank you!

Comment: How deep to you want to hide ? If both are on different servers, they can see the IP / Geo localisation / ASnumber / reverse DNS / http 404 specific error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have forum.abc123.com proxy def456.com/forum.  Sort of like (if your using apache):

```
<virtualhost *:80>
   servername forum.abc123.com
   proxypass / http://def456.com/forum/
   proxypassreverse / http://def456.com/forum/  
</virtualhost>
```

Although setting up the forums under forum.abc123.com in the first place would be easier.

Comment: Problem with this is I'm using cpanel on shared hosting.  Dont think I can do this

Comment: You may be out of luck.  I looked around the cpanel demo and there doesn't appear to be support for proxying.

Comment: FYI I had to enable "proxy_module" and "proxy_http_module" in WAMPserver for this to work

Answer (score 0):

you could point forum.abc123.com to the def456.com and there setup a virtualhost to handle forum.abc123.com

You aren't trying to do illegal stuff, are you ?

Comment: LOL no.  Just hosting a forum for a friend's site on my server.
Could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: On your friend dns, make forum.abc123.com point to your server IP.
On your server, create a virtualhost which match forum.abc123.com and contains your forum stuff. That simple, even no need for /forum, point it directly to the good root folder